# OBS studio won't record audio only

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, obs-studio

I wanted to record only audio with OBS Studio. So I have created a new scene and added just Audio Capture Device (ALSA). Then I clicked on the Start recording...button. It recorded both screen and audio. So another time, I tried to replace ALSA with PulseAudio, but it went to the same result. So how can I record just audio via OBS Studio?

Comment: I see, that "as usual" my question is migrated. So why OBS Studio is not an application? Probably my understanding of applications is wrong. I thought that applications are all GUI, which supports a certain amount of help to a user.

Comment: The term "application" in this context refers to [software applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software). There are several types, the site [webapps.se] is for questions about a very specific type of *software application*. OBS Studio belongs to a different category. Basically anything that you have to install in your computer might be asked in [su], but defintely not in [webapps.se] (the exception are web browsers with some limitations). Please checkout [Finding hard to fit into right site between Super User and Web Applications](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14924/152004)

Comment: Why do you want to use OBS if all you're interested in is audio? Why would you not use e.g. Audacity? OBS is mostly concerned with Video and Live Streaming. Only recording audio isn't what you'd usually use it for.

Answer (score 3):

To record only audio in OBS Studio, go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Output`, make sure `Advanced` mode is selected. Open `Recording` tab and choose `Custom Output (FFmpeg)` in dropdown. Choose e.g. `mp3` as container, disable `Video encoder` and edit the rest of settings to suit your needs.

This will save the output to `.mp3` directly and you can use a separate profile for that in case you're also using OBS for normal video recording.